# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64(copy constructor)

Tags: c++, xcode, compiler-construction

I have try to fix the function returning empty vector. I have did some google search, it shows  i need a copy constructor for the class `Point`, and  i keep receiving this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:   "Point::Point(Point const&)", referenced from:
      Core::render() in Week3_T.o
      Core::sortTriVertices(Point&, Point&, Point&) in Week3_T.o
      Core::decompose(std::__1::vector<Point, std::__1::allocator<Point> >) in Week3_T.o
      Core::drawTriangle(Point, Point, Point) in Week3_T.o
      Core::clipedge(std::__1::vector<Point, std::__1::allocator<Point> >, int, int, int, int) in Week3_T.o
      std::__1::enable_if<__is_forward_iterator<Point*>::value, void>::type std::__1::vector<Point, std::__1::allocator<Point>
>::__construct_at_end<Point*>(Point*, Point*) in Week3_T.o
      void std::__1::vector<Point, std::__1::allocator<Point> >::__push_back_slow_path<Point const>(Point const&) in Week3_T.o
      ... ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

and my class :

```
class Point
{
public:
    int x;
    int y;
    Uint8 r;
    Uint8 g;
    Uint8 b;
    Point(int x, int y, Uint8 r, Uint8 g, Uint8 b) : x(x), y(y), r(r), g(g), b(b) {}
    Point& operator=(Point const &np){
        x=np.x;
        y=np.y;
        r=np.r;
        g=np.g;
        b=np.b;
        return *this;
    }
    Point(const Point& );
    Point(){}


};
```

and snippet of code:

```
std::vector<Point> Core::clipedge(vector<Point> polygon, int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1)
{

    int r=rand()%255;
    int g=rand()%255;
    int b=rand()%255;
    // For each side of the polygon, check the 4 cases of sutherland-hodgman.
    // Creating a temporary buffer to hold your new set of vertices for the clipped polygon.
    std::vector<Point> temp;
    temp.push_back(Point(1,2,255,255,255));
    int size = (int)polygon.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
       {....}
       //push_back clipped point
       temp.push_back(p1);
       {....}
    }
    return temp;
```

system is OSX10.9.2 and ide is xcode5.1.1 compiler is apple llvm5.1

What i need to do to fix this? thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has been pointed out in other answers, you have not provided the definition of `Point::Point(const Point&)`, but you have declared it in your `Point` class definition. But your class requires no special handling of copy and assignment, so the solution to your problem is **not** to provide the missing definitions, but to remove the declaration of the copy constructor. Remove the assignment operator too:

```
class Point
{
public:
    int x;
    int y;
    Uint8 r;
    Uint8 g;
    Uint8 b;
    Point(int x, int y, Uint8 r, Uint8 g, Uint8 b) 
    : x(x), y(y), r(r), g(g), b(b) {}
};
```

The compiler-synthesized versions will do the right thing.

Comment: Thanks for help, how to determine whether is need a copy constructor or not?

Comment: @user3508896 You really need them if you need to do anything other than copy (or assign) the data members.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that you didn't define `Point(const Point& );` in your *.C file....
It compiles, because you've declared in the *.h file, but fails when trying to link because the symbol that other parts of the code refers to, cannot be found among the object files or libraries.

Comment: OMG, i did define it in .c file, just accidentally deleted. Thanks a lot.

Comment: is strange, my function still returning empty vector, i will post another question. please help, thanks a lot.