# C++[Clang++]: arm64 ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: c++, macos, clang, clang++, arm64

I am a c++ beginner and this is my first time to write c++ in a mac environment using clang++, I had make sure clang++ had been used correctly by compile a simple program, and it runs perfectly.

The problem is I cannot compile the program in mac environment after separating the files to multiple files and using `include` to link them, as well as trying to implement OOP to my sudoku and link 2 class together.

So I believe there might be something wrong related to the linker or my OOP method.

I found this article might be useful but I had tried to follow the recommend method but seems doesn't work:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23179099/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64copy-constructor](https://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/23179099/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64copy-constructor)

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74086956/c-macos-m1-ld-symbols-not-found-for-architecture-arm64-clang-error](https://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/74086956/c-macos-m1-ld-symbols-not-found-for-architecture-arm64-clang-error)

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73864774/ld-symbols-not-found-for-architecture-arm64-c](https://www.stackoverflow.com/73864774/ld-symbols-not-found-for-architecture-arm64-c)

There are some other information in the internet related to "I defined a function / variable in header files but did not implemented it in the .cpp files", I don't think this is the case for me. As all defined function in header files has been implemented already. There is a few line that I am not sure did the contributor do it properly and it might be related (most likely they are able to compile with gnu g++ in wsl/linux without the most correct syntax) which are:

Sudoku.cpp

```cpp
Sudoku::Sudoku(int boardHeight, int boardWidth) : Board(boardHeight, boardWidth) {}
```

as well as how he defined and implemented the relationship between the board and sudoku

The error message is at bellow

compile to compile : `clang++ -std=c++20 main.cpp`

```
//Error message
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "Sudoku::initialize(int)", referenced from:
      _main in main-ec9303.o
  "Sudoku::drawBoard()", referenced from:
      _main in main-ec9303.o
  "Sudoku::Sudoku(int, int)", referenced from:
      _main in main-ec9303.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Here is the source code: https://github.com/potatochick2020/Sudoku-core

Minimal code to post here (might not be that minimal):

main.cpp

```cpp
//main.cpp
#include "Sudoku.h"

int main()
{
    Sudoku sudoku;
    sudoku.initialize();
    sudoku.drawBoard();
}
```

Sudoku.h

```cpp
//Sudoku.h
#pragma once
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <stack>
#include <map>
#include <numeric>

#include "Board.h"

#define SHUFFLE(x) shuffle(x.begin(), x.end(), mt19937{ random_device{}() });
#define CANDIDATE_ARRAY { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0 }

using namespace std;

class Sudoku : public Board
{
private:
    bool GenerateSudoku(void);
public:
    Sudoku(int boardHeight = 9, int boardWidth = 9);
    // default argument only in decleration
    void initialize(int difficulty = 3);
    //overloading for a Board::setBoard 
    void setBoard(int, int, int);
    void setBoard(vector<vector<int>>);
    virtual void drawBoard();
    bool isCorrect(void);
    bool isComplete(void);
    bool isValid(void);
    bool isPlacable(int, int, int);
    int SudokuSolution(void);
};
```

Board.h

```cpp
#pragma once
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

// Abstract Class since it has an abstract function
class Board
{
protected:
    vector<vector<int>> board;
    int boardWidth, boardHeight;
    Board(int, int);
    // Abstaract function that must be defined by children
    virtual void drawBoard() = 0;
public:
    vector<vector<int>> getBoard();
    void setBoard(vector<vector<int>> newBoard);
};
```

Board.cpp

```cpp
#pragma once
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

// Abstract Class since it has an abstract function
class Board
{
protected:
    vector<vector<int>> board;
    int boardWidth, boardHeight;
    Board(int, int);
    // Abstaract function that must be defined by children
    virtual void drawBoard() = 0;
public:
    vector<vector<int>> getBoard();
    void setBoard(vector<vector<int>> newBoard);
};
```

Sudoku.cpp

```cpp
#include "Sudoku.h"

Sudoku::Sudoku(int boardHeight, int boardWidth) : Board(boardHeight, boardWidth) {}

bool Sudoku::isValid()
{
    unordered_set<int> set;
    int tar = 0;
    // check horizontal
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        set.clear();
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
        {
            if (board[i][j] != tar && set.find(board[i][j]) != set.end())
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                set.insert(board[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
    // check vertical
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        set.clear();
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
        {
            if (board[j][i] != tar && set.find(board[j][i]) != set.end())
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                set.insert(board[j][i]);
            }
        }
    }
    // check 3x3 box
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            set.clear();
            for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
            {
                for (int l = 0; l < 3; l++)
                {
                    if (board[i * 3 + k][j * 3 + l] != tar && set.find(board[i * 3 + k][j * 3 + l]) != set.end())
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        set.insert(board[i * 3 + k][j * 3 + l]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}

bool Sudoku::isComplete()
{
    for (int row = 0; row < 9; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < 9; col++)
        {
            if (board[row][col] == 0)
                return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

bool Sudoku::isCorrect(void)
{
    return isValid() && isComplete();
}

bool Sudoku::isPlacable(int i, int j, int value)
{
    for (int idx = 0; idx < 9; idx++)
    {
        if (board[i][idx] == value)
            return false;
        if (board[idx][j] == value)
            return false;
        if (board[(i / 3) * 3 + (idx / 3)][(j / 3) * 3 + (idx % 3)] == value)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

void Sudoku::setBoard(int row, int col, int value)
{
    board[row][col] = value;
}

bool Sudoku::GenerateSudoku()
{
    vector<int> numbers(9);

    while (isComplete() == false)
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < 9; row++)
        {

            for (int col = 0; col < 9; col++)
            {

                if (board[row][col] == 0)
                {
                    // fills out the numbers vector with numbers from 1 -> numbers.size()
                    iota(begin(numbers), end(numbers), 1);
                    SHUFFLE(numbers);
                    for (int number : numbers)
                    {
                        if (isPlacable(row, col, number))
                        {
                            // if (true){
                            board[row][col] = number;
                            if (Sudoku::GenerateSudoku())
                                return true;
                            board[row][col] = 0;
                        }
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

int Sudoku::SudokuSolution()
{
    int ans = 0;
    vector<int> numbers(9);

    // fills out the numbers vector with numbers from 1 -> numbers.size()
    iota(begin(numbers), end(numbers), 1);
    for (int row = 0; row < 9; row++)
    {

        for (int col = 0; col < 9; col++)
        {
            if (board[row][col] == 0)
            {
                for (int number : numbers)
                {
                    if (isPlacable(row, col, number))
                    {
                        board[row][col] = number;

                        if (isCorrect())
                            ans++;
                        else
                            ans += Sudoku::SudokuSolution();

                        board[row][col] = 0;
                    }
                }
                return ans;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void Sudoku::initialize(int difficulty)
{
    GenerateSudoku();
    vector<int> rowsCandidates = CANDIDATE_ARRAY;
    SHUFFLE(rowsCandidates);
    vector<int> colsCandidates = CANDIDATE_ARRAY;
    SHUFFLE(colsCandidates);
    pair<pair<int, int>, int> backup = {{rowsCandidates[0], colsCandidates[0]}, board[rowsCandidates[0]][colsCandidates[0]]};
    board[rowsCandidates[0]][colsCandidates[0]] = 0;

    int attempt = 0;
    while (attempt < difficulty)
    {

        rowsCandidates = CANDIDATE_ARRAY;
        SHUFFLE(rowsCandidates);

        colsCandidates = CANDIDATE_ARRAY;
        SHUFFLE(colsCandidates);

        backup = {{rowsCandidates[0], colsCandidates[0]}, board[rowsCandidates[0]][colsCandidates[0]]};
        board[rowsCandidates[0]][colsCandidates[0]] = 0;
        if (SudokuSolution() > 1)
        {
            board[backup.first.first][backup.first.second] = backup.second;
            attempt++;
        }
    }
};

void Sudoku::drawBoard()
{
    // this implementation done by @AshishRaikwar1290
    for (int row = 0; row < boardHeight; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < boardHeight; col++)
        {
            if (col == 3 || col == 6)
                cout << " | ";
            cout << board[row][col] << " ";
        }
        if (row == 2 || row == 5)
        {
            cout << endl;
            for (int i = 0; i < boardHeight; i++)
                cout << "---";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

I expect it could compile properly, and when i do `./a.out`, it should print a sudoku out. (see drawBoard() in Sudoku.cpp)

Comment: How do you *build* your code? Do you remember to build with all source files? Link with all object files?

Comment: clang++ -std=c++20 main.cpp This is the only line I do... Should I make a make file instead?

Comment: You need to list *all* source files when you're building. How would the compiler and linker otherwise know what files you want to build with?

Comment: On a totally different note: `using namespace std;` [is a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) when done in a source file. Doing it in a header file should be considered plain wrong.

Comment: For everyone who encounter this issue:

This is because you did not build with all source file as mentioned by @Someprogrammerdude , the solution is `clang++ -std="c++20" -o test Main.cpp Sudoku.cpp Board.cpp ` replace `clang++` with `g++ `if you are using gnu g++.